# Unity 'score does not exist in the current context'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, int, void

So I'm trying to make it so when I touch a **coin** (Sprite, It's a 2D game) it gets destroyed and i get a point up, but the problem is, that it says that *score* does not exist in the current context.

**UNITY ERROR:**
(Assets/_SCRIPTS/TextScore.cs(11,61): error CS0103: The name `score' does not exist in the current context)

**CODE:**

```
using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;
  using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.Impl;
  using UnityEngine.UI;
  using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
  public class CodeSystem : MonoBehaviour {
  // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {

   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update () {

   }
   int score = 0;
   void OnCollisionEnter ( Collider other )
   {
       Debug.Log("Picked up coin!");
       if (tag == "Coin")
       {
           Debug.Log("Added score!");
           score = score + 1;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error is in `TextScore.cs` and you have shown `CodeSystem.cs`

Comment: well... that's awkward

Comment: How do i get the `score` across from `CodeSystem.cs` to `TextScore.cs` ?

Comment: You should mark the `score` as static, e.g. with `public static int score;`, then you access it from any script through `CodeSystem.score` (so this question is actually about variable scope), but let's see the code first.

Comment: `static` is not the answer to every reference problem, Max.  In this case it will work and probably not destroy anything, the more general solution is "you need a reference to an instance of your CodeSystem."

Comment: I think a popular approach with Unity is to make a public variable of type `CodeSystem` in your `TextScore` class, and in the editor view drag your instance of `CodeSystem` onto that field. (Oh, and either make `score` public, or create a publicly-accessible way to get it.) Then you can just retrieve `score` from your instance of CodeSystem`.